# Приложение с фрагментами

Tags: android

Хочу написать приложение для алфавита национального языка. Суть в следующем.

Имеется `MainActivity` где весь алфавит перечислен. Пользователь нажимает на какую-нибудь букву и открывается фрагмент для выбранной буквы примерно такое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда нажимает стрелку вперед переход к фрагменту со следующей буквой, а когда нажимает предыдущую, то переход к фрагменту с предыдущей буквой. В какую сторону копать для реализации такого типа приложения?

Как такое вообще реализовывается?

Comment: горизонтальный `RecyclerView`+текст под ним или `ViewPager`. Не понятно, что за кругляши - буквы/изображения/текст.

Comment: Кругляшки это для каждой буквы во фрагменте будут по три кнопки или картинки с предметами начинающимися на данную букву

Comment: А что лучше использовать RecyclerView или ViewPager в данном случае?

Comment: наверное, тогда пэйджер

Comment: пэйджер поместить в контейнер (например `FrameLayout`) и стрелки наложить там же сверху (в контейнере) - будет удобно)

Comment: Понял Спасибо..